# Keyword "returns" in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr3, antlr4

I'm currently adapting several ANTLR3 grammar files for ANTLR4. Some of the old ANTLR3 rules use the `returns` keyword. This rule is valid in both ANTLR3 and ANTLR4:

```
aRule:
  returns [String s]

  anotherRule AND (aRule)?
  {
      $s = "foo";
  }
;

...
```

Calling `parser.aRule()` on an ANTLR3 parser returns a `String`. Calling `parser.aRule()` on an ANTLR4 parser returns a `RuleContext`. Is the `returns` keyword in ANTLR4 purely for backward compatibility purposes? Obviously in both situations returns causes a public field `String s` to be added to the generated `ARuleContext`.

Would I be correct to assume ideally the `returns` keyword should no longer be used, and any sort of context state should be handled by a parse tree visitor?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if the `returns` is still used/valid. In most cases I traverse and transform the parse tree manually, but a parse tree visitor may also do in cases where you don't need the extra flexibility provided by custom walking the parse tree. So in short: forget about the `returns` and do post processing in code afterwards based on the parse tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would I be correct to assume ideally the returns keyword should no longer be used, and any sort of context state should be handled by a parse tree visitor?

Yes, that is correct. With ANTLR4, you should keep all target specific code outside of your grammar and moved into listeners/visitors.